# Web Api Controller with multiple POST and single PUT Methods

Tags: vb.net, asp.net-web-api

Based on the code below, I'm able to call /api/cards and /api/cards/list but now /api/cards/1234567890

WebApiConfig

```
config.Routes.MapHttpRoute( _
       name:="WithActionAndIdApi", _
       routeTemplate:="api/{controller}/{action}/{id}", _
       defaults:=New With {.id = RouteParameter.Optional} _
   )

    config.Routes.MapHttpRoute( _
        name:="WithIdApi", _
        routeTemplate:="api/{controller}/{id}" _
    )

    config.Routes.MapHttpRoute( _
        name:="DefaultApi", _
        routeTemplate:="api/{controller}", _
        defaults:=New With {.action = "DefaultAction"} _
    )
```

CardsController

```
<HttpPost()>
<ActionName("DefaultAction")>
Public Function PostValue(<FromBody()> ByVal value As Card_POST.Card) As HttpResponseMessage

<HttpPost()>
<ActionName("list")>
Public Function PostValue(<FromBody()> ByVal value As Cards_POST.CardList) As HttpResponseMessage

<HttpPut()>
Public Function PutValue(ByVal Id As String, <FromBody()> ByVal value As Card_PUT) As HttpResponseMessage
```

Comment: please make sure you are asking a question.  It is unclear what problem you are having or what you are attempting to solve.

Comment: How you do the PUT request?

Comment: @Mate, I've solved the issue by changing my config.Routes

Comment: Great! Congratulations! Mark as correct your own answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've changed my config.Routes into below code and it is able to support my situation above.

```
config.Routes.MapHttpRoute( _
       name:="DefaultApiWithId", _
       routeTemplate:="api/{controller}/{id}", _
       defaults:=New With {.id = RouteParameter.Optional}, _
       constraints:=New With {.id = "^\d+$"} _
    )

    config.Routes.MapHttpRoute( _
       name:="DefaultApiWithAction", _
       routeTemplate:="api/{controller}/{action}" _
   )

    config.Routes.MapHttpRoute( _
       name:="DefaultApiGet", _
       routeTemplate:="api/{controller}/{id}", _
       defaults:=New With {.id = RouteParameter.Optional}, _
       constraints:=New With {.httpMethod = New HttpMethodConstraint({"GET"})} _
   )

    config.Routes.MapHttpRoute( _
       name:="DefaultApiPost", _
       routeTemplate:="api/{controller}", _
       defaults:=New With {.action = "DefaultPostAction"}, _
       constraints:=New With {.httpMethod = New HttpMethodConstraint({"POST"})} _
   )

    config.Routes.MapHttpRoute( _
       name:="DefaultApiPut", _
       routeTemplate:="api/{controller}/{id}", _
       defaults:=Nothing, _
       constraints:=New With {.httpMethod = New HttpMethodConstraint({"PUT"})} _
   )
```